# Unpack initramfs.cpio.gz (boot.img) from MTK6589 phone?

Tags: custom-roms, boot, device-firmware

I can't find a proper tool to unpack boot.img from GravityMod2.

both `unmkbootimg` and `split_bootimg.pl` are able to extract same fileset (kernel, 4280320 bytes and ramdisk, 633284 bytes). I think the files are damaged (taken from wrong offsets?) - can't even find gzip/cpio signatures in ramdisk image!

Is there another specific tool to unpack Android 4.2.x boot.img, or MTK-specific tool maybe?

Comment: Yes, there were specific tools. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1587411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find proper tools to unpack boot, recovery, system and data images here:
[mtk-tools](https://github.com/bgcngm/mtk-tools)

[Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1587411) of the author on xda developers, thank him :)

Usage:

```
./unpack-MT65xx.pl boot.img
./repack-MT65xx.pl -boot <kernel> <ramdisk-directory> boot.img
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem extracting initramfs.cpio.gz , until I opened this file in editor and seen first 3 ascii letters  (the header) in my case it was "LZO" , so I found proper soft to decompress 
"lzop -x " you can find it probably in every linux, for example knoppix has it

maybe you will notice other header in your file , so you will need to google it or have a good guess

good luck